# What does "a martyr to distraction" mean?

Tags: meaning

Oblonsky says to Levin:

> Oblonsky: You marry for love. You're a good husband. Children arrive, years depart.
> And all of a sudden, your wife grows old and tired. And her hair is thin.
> And her body...And you yourself, you still have your vigor!
> And then you find yourself a **martyr to distraction** by so many women.

What does "a martyr to distraction" mean?

Comment: I assume "Anna Karenina" again.  Can you tell us which translation this is?  It is a very long book So please tell which part and chapter this is from.  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a complicated and unusual metaphor.

A martyr is a person who dies (or is ready to die) for their beliefs.

The man in question no longer finds his wife attractive and **gives himself up/surrenders himself** to distraction by other women.

Distraction commands his life.

Comment: You can also be 'a martyr to' a chronic disease or unpleasant symptom, such as headaches. The speaker could mean that he is constantly being distracted from fidelity to his wife by the temptation of other women.